# SQL returns the unique identifier instead of the value in my Access UNON ALL SQL

Tags: sql, database, ms-access

So here is my project using MS Access 2010,
I have developed 2 queries to select 2 different reading periods.  These queries are called CycleStart and CycleEnd.  When I run these 2 queries individually I get expected output results. these 2 queries pull data from tables with a couple lookup fields in them.  So the lookup fields use other tables where there are only 2 columns. The next step I use SQL to create a UNION ALL query to bring these 2 cycle queries together for reporting purposes.  The problem I run into is that my resulting Union query does not output the same information as the 2 individual cycle queries.

Now the specific issues.  My cycle queries have a couple lookup fields referencing another table.  For example the Read_Cycle field comes for a table(Read_Cycles) and only has 2 columns, the unique identifer assigned by Access and the Read_Cycle column with the data I enter.  When I run the cycle queries the field for Read_Cycle returns the Read_Cycle data as expected, but the union query does not. So here is some structure of my project:

Read_Cycles Table

```
|ID Col1 | |Cycle_ID Col2|
    1             Spring
    2             Fall
    3             Winter
```

The data tables behind the CycleStart and the CycleEnd have fields that are lookup values referencing the above described Read_Cycles table.

Query CycleStart and CycleEnd return Spring or fall or winter, which ever value is associated with the record, correctly.

however, the problem I have is that the Union SQL Query returns the ID instead of the value, so instead of getting Fall, I get the 2.

Here is my UNION ALL SQL........

```
SELECT "CycleEnd" AS source,
    [CycleEnd].[Recloser_SerialNo],
    [CycleEnd].[Read_Date],
    [CycleEnd].[3_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[A_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[B_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[C_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[Read_Cycle],
    [CycleEnd].[PoleNo],
    [CycleEnd].[Substation],
    [CycleEnd].[Feeder],
    [CycleEnd].[Feeder_Description],
    [CycleEnd].[Recloser_Location]
FROM [CycleEnd]

UNION ALL

SELECT "CycleStart" AS source,
    [CycleStart].[Recloser_SerialNo],
    [CycleStart].[Read_Date],
    [CycleStart].[3_Phase_Reading] * - 1,
    [CycleStart].[A_Phase_Reading] * - 1,
    [CycleStart].[B_Phase_Reading] * - 1,
    [CycleStart].[C_Phase_Reading] * - 1,
    [CycleStart].[Read_Cycle],
    [CycleStart].[PoleNo],
    [CycleStart].[Substation],
    [CycleStart].[Feeder],
    [CycleStart].[Feeder_Description],
    [CycleStart].[Recloser_Location]
FROM [CycleStart];
```

All other fields are coming across just fine and as expected, I have narrowed it down to only fields that are a lookup in the original tables.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Also my SQL experience is really limited so example code would help greatly.

UPDATE:
here is the sql from the CycleEnd that works.  I got this by building the query then changing to the SQL view...

```
SELECT Recloser_Readings.Recloser_SerialNo,
    Recloser_Readings.Read_Date,
    Recloser_Readings.[3_Phase_Reading],
    Recloser_Readings.A_Phase_Reading,
    Recloser_Readings.B_Phase_Reading,
    Recloser_Readings.C_Phase_Reading,
    Recloser_Locations.PoleNo,
    Recloser_Locations.Substation,
    Recloser_Locations.Feeder,
    Recloser_Locations.Feeder_Description,
    Recloser_Locations.Recloser_Location,
    Recloser_Readings.Read_Cycle
FROM (
    Recloser_Inventory LEFT JOIN Recloser_Locations
        ON Recloser_Inventory.PoleNo = Recloser_Locations.PoleNo
    )
RIGHT JOIN Recloser_Readings
    ON Recloser_Inventory.Serial_No = Recloser_Readings.Recloser_SerialNo
WHERE (((Recloser_Readings.Read_Cycle) = "8"));
```

UPDATE#2
I noticed I grabbed the wrong code that references the Read_Cycles table.  Here it is...

```
SELECT Read_Cycles.Cycle_ID, Read_Cycles.ID
```

FROM Read_Cycles
ORDER BY Read_Cycles.Cycle_ID DESC;

UPDATE : SYNTAX ERROR FROM THE FOLLOWING CODE!!

```
SELECT "CycleEnd" as source, 
    [CycleEnd].[Recloser_SerialNo], 
    [CycleEnd].[Read_Date],
    [CycleEnd].[3_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[A_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[B_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[C_Phase_Reading],
    [CycleEnd].[Read_Cycle],
    [CycleEnd].[PoleNo],
    [CycleEnd].[Substation],
    [CycleEnd].[Feeder],
    [CycleEnd].[Feeder_Description],
    [CycleEnd].[Recloser_Location]
```

FROM [CycleEnd] JOIN [Read_Cycles] ON [CycleEnd].[Read_Cycle] = [Read_Cycles].[ID]

```
UNION ALL SELECT "CycleStart" as source,
    [CycleStart].[Recloser_SerialNo], 
    [CycleStart].[Read_Date],
    [CycleStart].[3_Phase_Reading]*-1,
    [CycleStart].[A_Phase_Reading]*-1,
    [CycleStart].[B_Phase_Reading]*-1,
    [CycleStart].[C_Phase_Reading]*-1,
    [CycleStart].[Read_Cycle],
    [CycleStart].[PoleNo],
    [CycleStart].[Substation],
    [CycleStart].[Feeder],
    [CycleStart].[Feeder_Description],
    [CycleStart].[Recloser_Location]
```

FROM [CycleStart] JOIN [Read_Cycles] ON [CycleStart].[Read_Cycle] = [Read_Cycles].[ID];

Comment: This likely will not solve the problem overall, but it caught my eye. You are performing calculations on four of the columns in the second half of the union. Whenever I have does this I typically find that it loses the column name information, unless I give it an alias. UNION queries require the same column headings on both sides on the union, so you may want to alias those four columns (back to their original names) to avoid potential errors.

Comment: Could you share one of the statements, which do actually return the wanted result. Basically, based on your description, I'd expect to see some `JOIN` to the "Read_Cycles" table…

Comment: AbeeCee  Look at the original post for the update section.  The query that works is shown there in the SQL format..

Comment: Joe.  The reason I did the calculation here is because I am trying to find the difference between 2 readings in a report.  The TOTALS option does not do subtraction, so a work around I found on line was to do this union query and multiply one by  a -1 then I can use the sum feature in the TOTALS options in reports.  Hope that makes since..

Comment: AbeeCee - I think I grabbed the wrong statement, so I grabbed the one that references the Read_Cycles table you asked for.  It is under Update#2 above.

Comment: You will likely need something along `…, Read_Cycles.Cycle_ID, … FROM CycleEnd JOIN Read_Cycles ON CycleEnd.Read_Cycle = Read_Cycles.ID` (or the other way around depending on the meaning of the columns in "Read_Cycles"), and similarly for "CycleStart" to get the actual values instead of the keys into your result set.

Comment: @pcorun - I'm not saying there's anything wrong with calculated values, you can do whatever you want to them. I'm just suggesting using something like `[CycleStart].[3_Phase_Reading] * - 1 as [3_Phase_Reading],` instead of just `[CycleStart].[3_Phase_Reading] * - 1,` to avoid a `(no column name)` output. That said, I'm used to Microsoft SSMS using TSQL. MS Access might not have this issue, I'm not sure.

Comment: As for the calculation you seem to anticipate to do with the result set: You might want to change from a `UNION` to a `JOIN` between the two subselects. This would allow you to do the calculation straight in the SQL rather than later on.

Comment: AbeeCee, I updated my SQL to include your recommended code, but get a syntax error.  I have posted the updated code in up in to original post for you to see.  I tried the additional code with the brackets and without the brackets, but get the same resulting syntax error.. any suggestions?

Comment: If this is still relevant to you: (i) Could you possibly create a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with sample data to play with? (Yes, there is no access in SQL Fiddle. But once your problem is properly understood, it will be much easier to assist you.) (ii) Is there any more detail about the reported syntax error? (iii) If some of the code was added by error, and is not really relevant - please remove it. (Sorry but: 74 views and no answer seems to suggest, something to be missing from your problem statement.)

Comment: Is this still relevant to you?